# Finding an equation for multiple variable

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, change-of-variable

**Updated Version**

Let's say, $y$ is my target value. And $p,q,r,s,t$ are the variables that change $y$ (basic 2D curves found from interpolation). My goal is to find an equation for solving $y$ when all the variables are present. I have the following source:

One scenario: $y$ changes with change of $p$ while other variables are constant. Basic 2D curve found from interpolation.

Similar scenarios for $q,r,s,t$.

- How do I find an equation for each scenario? (including the effects of the constant variables)
- Is it possible to find a master equation for $y$ when all the variables are variable?

Comment: It is nor very clear (at least to me).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Updated the question. Hope you'll like it :)

Comment: Done, sir! @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Since my first attempt doesn't seem to have been what you wanted, I've re-read your re-phrased statement...and it doesn't seem any clearer to me. Perhaps someone else can make sense of it. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, sir. My perception has been getting clearer since you answered to the question and I rephrased it. Next time, I'll be up with a better question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm interpreting your question correctly.

If so, in general, the answer is no. Consider a function of two variables, $a$ and $b$. Suppose that $x$, as a function of $a$, is $a + 1$ when $b = 0$. 
$$
x(a, 0) = a + 1
$$
And suppose that $x$, as a function of $b$, is $b+2$ when $a = 0$:
$$
x(0, b) = b + 2
$$
Let 
$$
f(a, b) = a + b + 3
$$

Then $f$ is a function that *matches the two known properties* of $x$.

But now also consider
$$
g(a, b) = a + b + 3 + ab
$$

The function $g$ *also* matches the two known properties of $x$. Since there are two possible solutions, in general it's impossible to find "the" function that matches your given data.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your analogy. I see what you mean.

Here, $f(a,b)$ seems to be the sum of $x(a,0)$ and $x(0,b)$. But I'm looking for the value of $x$ in all cases. Pardon my lack of understanding.

The question has been improved and it is very clear now. I'm flattered by your time spent :)